# how to show spinner in modal until response comes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Image in modal doesn't show right away, and I think its because it is empty until response comes. So I would like to show spinner in modal before I get response. How can I show spinner inside modal until image is ready?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `img` tag with your spinner gif on the `modal`, and just `.hide()` it on your `.then` function